# .htccess 301 redirect for domains, https, www, and file extention

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a few domain names, and recently updated my website to be run from a single file (index.php). Request URI is the same other than no .php . My host is GoDaddy linux unlimited (yeah...).

I require my .htaccess to redirect/rewrite the following

- Redirect domain1.com to www.primary.com
- Redirect www.domain1.com to www.primary.com
- Redirect domain2.com to www.primary.com
- Redirect www.domain2.com to www.primary.com
- Force https://
- Force www.
- Remove .php from any requests (/marketing/cost.php to /marketing/cost)
- Remove trailing slashes

Im currently using the following code to pass all request to index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The index.php file handles all request. Based on *($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])* index.php loads in content from database.

I know trailing slashes are recommended, but would prefer to keep off; i think domain.com/sec/nom?x=23 looks better than domain.com/sec/nom/?x=23

---

I have attempt a few variations in .htaccess my self, and work locally, but not on GoDaddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.primary\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.primary.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, all works except for trailing slash, but fixed that by adding:

RedirectMatch 301 ^(.+)/$ $1

Comment: Yep, Works perfectly. Thank You